# Get sql results based on like '123%' using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate 4 and I have the following code in my DAO class where I would like to 
get results from my table

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> c = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> emp = c.from(Employee.class);
        c.select(emp);
List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class,
                "employeeNumber");
Predicate predicate = cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.employeeNumber),
                pexp);

        criteria.add(predicate);

if (criteria.size() == 1) {
            c.where(criteria.get(0));           
        } else if (criteria.size() > 1) {
            c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

        }

TypedQuery<Employee> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);
if (employeeNumber != null) {
            q.setParameter("employeeNumber", employeeNumber);
data.setResult(q.getResultList());
```

When page runs, from log I could see sql as

```
select employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER as EMPLOYEE1_0_ from EMPLOYEES employeede0_ 
where employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER like ?
```

Because of this I am not able to see any results. Ideally I would like to have a query like

```
select employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER as EMPLOYEE1_0_ from EMPLOYEES employeede0_ 
    where employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER like '123%'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: ? means hibernate will be getting this value at runtime.You cant see that value in the log.You have to make sure that you are setting the property correctly.

Comment: @Renjith so `like ?` means it is executing as `EMPLOYEE_NUMBER like '123%'? ` Besides how can I set it properly?

Comment: @KevinBowersox Yes it is, `public static volatile SingularAttribute<Employee, String> employeeNumber;`

Comment: Example : [.add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )] http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to end up executing

```
Predicate predicate = cb.like("employeeNumber", "123%");
```

So including the percent.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have managed like this `Predicate predicate = cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.empName),
    empName+"%");` If I would want to have case sensitive statement, how could I sorround with lower()?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how you mean, `ilike()` is the case insensitive version of `like()` so I'd expect this to be case sensitive. I have not tried it out, though. In the documentation, I see that SimpleExpression has a method ignoreCase() so you could try `Predicate predicate = cb.like("employeeNumber", "123%").ignoreCase();`

Comment: `Predicate predicate = cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.empName), empName+"%");` doesn't have `ignoreCase();` method.

Comment: But it is a SimpleExpression too. So change Predicate to that.

Comment: Flup I have managed to get this working using metamodel. `Predicate predicate = cb.like(cb.lower(emp.get(Employee_.empName)),
            empName.toLowerCase() + "%");` Courtesy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333997/jpa-2-criteria-api-using-metamodel-case-sensitive-condition)  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: My pleasure! ( I still suspect that `Predicate predicate = cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.empName), empName+"%").ignoreCase();` will work too. )

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
criteria.add ( Restrictions.like ("employeeNumber", "123%" ) );
```