# JPA 2 Criteria API using metamodel case sensitive condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following line of code to get the results based on like statement using Hibernate 4 API

```
Predicate predicate = cb.like(emp.get(EmployeeDetail_.empName),
                empName+"%");
```

The generated sql statement is

```
 select employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NAME as EMPLOYEE1_0_ from EMPLOYEES employeede0_ 
        where employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NAME like 'smith%'
```

How can I modify my java code to have EMPLOYEE_NAME in lower case? The generated sql output should be like the following

```
select employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NAME as EMPLOYEE1_0_ from EMPLOYEES employeede0_ 
    where lower(employeede0_.EMPLOYEE_NAME) like lower('smith%')
```

Complete code for getting results

```
   CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Employee> c = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
        Root<Employee> emp = c.from(Employee.class);
        c.select(emp);
        List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        ParameterExpression<String> pexp = cb.parameter(String.class,
                "empName");
        Predicate predicate = cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.empName),
                empName+"%");
        criteria.add(predicate);

        if (criteria.size() == 1) {
            c.where(criteria.get(0));
        } else if (criteria.size() > 1) {
            c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        }
        TypedQuery<EmployeeDetail> q = entityManager.createQuery(c);
        data.setResult(q.getResultList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [CriteriaBuilder#lower()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#lower%28javax.persistence.criteria.Expression%29):

```
Predicate predicate = cb.like(cb.lower(emp.get(EmployeeDetail_.empName)),
            empName.toLowerCase() + "%");
```

Comment: For some strange reason no results are coming when this gets executed. Generated sql is `select  employeede0_.EMP_NAME as LONG2_0_ from V_EMPLOYEE employeede0_ where low
er(employeede0_.EMP_NAME) like ?`

Comment: The query seems correct however... maybe the problem is somewhere else? What is the value of the parameter `empName`?

Comment: Value of `empName` is getting it correctly, e.g. value coming as `'smith'` Any way we could see the sql statement instead of question mark(?) ?

Comment: I have found quite a strange thing, `System.out.println(" size "+q.getResultList().size());`. This prints real count of the sql results, however cannot see any records in jsf page.

Comment: Great. Ensure that the query returns the correct result set. If it does, ask a new question with the new problem adding the relevant information.

Comment: Problem has been solved. I have to make a similar change in my ManagedBean as well, something like `empName.toLowerCase();` Thanks a lot for your help.